# Why is there "undefined" text in my html when making an API call

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting undefined text in the HTML when I make this API call? There are no errors in the console. I'm kind of new to working with APIs so any advice would be helpful.

The following is how I'm making the call:

```
// Load list of blog posts
window.onload = function() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=1')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((posts) => {
          let output;
          posts.forEach(function(post) {
            output += `
            <li class="post">
                <h2><a href="#" target="_blank">${post.title}</a></h2>
                <p>${post.body}</p>
            </li>
            `
        });
        document.querySelector('#posts').innerHTML = output;
    });
};
```

Here is a visual image of the output:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize the output variable with an empty string first before concatenating.

```
let output = "";
```

Comment: Thanks Tihomir! That worked.